# Header Won't Position: Absolute

Tags: html, css, header

I'm trying to find a simple fix to get my header to stay in a fixed position, but when I apply "position:fixed" to my header class nothing happens. I tried it with the h1 tag in the header too. I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong and what the simplest method would be to get the header to stay fixed when you scroll down the screen. I pasted the header section below.

Thank you for all suggestions!

```
 <header class="logo">
    <h1>The Loch Ness Monster Report</h1>
    <ul id="nav-menu">
        <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">Latest Sightings</a></li>
        <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Report a Sighting</a></li>
        <li><a href="donations.html">Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

The CSS is working because the other elements are connected. This is what I'm using for the CSS for the header element.

```
.logo {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 }
```

Comment: Add CSS maybe? Also your head content to make sure you are linking your css.

Comment: i included the CSS element. is it not possible to absolute position the entire header or something?

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle , paste all your html and css code on jsfiddle.nett and share the link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=cSTlrK2Cyd

Comment: I added the JS Fiddle link. The header in purple is supposed to stay in position: fixed, while the other elements scroll underneath it.

Comment: @Dog cant see anything in your demo..please save the fiddle and share the url

Comment: Don't forget to close your question, by accepting one of the answers. So other people can refer back to this question in case this question was answered properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```css
header{
  width: 100vw; //set header width equal to viewport width.

}
.logo {
 position: fixed; //set header fix to top 
 z-index: 1;
 display: flex; // displays  logo content horizontally
 justify-content: flex-start; // set logo content 
 flex-direction: row;
 height: auto;
 background: #000000;
 color: white;
 }
 #nav-menu{
   display: flex; 
   flex-direction: row;  //display lost horizontally
 }
 h1{
   font-size: 140%;
 }
 li{
   padding: 5px;
   list-style: none;
 }
 a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white
 }
 li:hover{
   background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
 }
 a:hover{
   color: red;


 }

 body{
   // reset body properties
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }
.container{
  padding-top: 60px;
}
 section{
   height: 500px;
   width: 960px;
 }
.section1{
  background-color: blue;
}
.section2{
  background-color: orange;
}
.section3{
  background-color:  red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="logo">
        <h1>The Loch Ness Monster Report</h1>
        <ul id="nav-menu">
            <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">Latest Sightings</a></li>
            <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Report a Sighting</a></li>
            <li><a href="donations.html">Donate</a></li>
        </ul>

  </header>
  <div class="container">
  <Section class="section1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </Section>
  <Section class="section2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </Section>
  <Section class="section3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </Section>
  </div>
  </body>
```